# How to view serilog records from SQL Server with Seq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, serilog, seq-logging

I use ASP.NET MVC and serilog, I want to read and view and analyze recorded logs with [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) in sql server, I find [seq](https://docs.getseq.net/v3/docs/getting-started) that let to add logs to seq like:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
```

That is perfect I could add the logs to seq and check them. But I want to view and read logs that already stored in Sql server:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, tableName, columnOptions: columnOptions)
    .CreateLogger();
```

So I already have records in DB, is there any way to read the records in Sql server with seq? or does any one have any idea with another free tool to read the serilog records from sql server?

Comment: Hi @Saeid! Would exporting the data from SQL Server into Seq be an option? I can't think of any interfaces to logs in SQL Server as nice as Seq's one (I may be biased ;-)) so that seems like the natural approach to take.

Comment: Hi @NicholasBlumhardt, Unfortunately no.

Comment: Is there any library to present XML?

Answer (score 1):

Seq uses its own data store and not a database like SQL.  It is file based data store.  [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) or SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is how I currently query our Serilog database log.

Links to Seq's documentation:

- Data store: http://docs.getseq.net/docs/data-store
- File storage: http://docs.getseq.net/docs/storage-paths-and-urls

One can also write a conversion program to push the data from SQL to Seq.  You can use either of the following methods to get the data into Seq.  Once it is in then use the Seq interface for querying.

- https://docs.getseq.net/v3/docs/importing-log-files
- https://docs.getseq.net/v3/docs/posting-raw-events

Comment: Well I need to read logs from sql server. may be another tools did that